# mapping between an object and a dynamically created object after JSON deserialization

Tags: c#, json, object, dynamic, mapping

How do I do a mapping between an object created by instantiating a class and a dynamic object created by a JSON deserialization (JsonConvert) considering I don't know the dynamic object's fields? In other words, I'd like to update the dynamic object fields matching by name.

This is my example code:

```
string json = {\"NDG\":7803, \"NumberOfNights\":2, \"Nome\":\"Ago\", \"Cognome\":\"Mar\", \"CognomeNome\":\"\"};
string djson = ?? //I don't know the structure coming from a call as parameter but I know there are some json string identical fields  

public class myVars
{
    public string Userid { get; set; }
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    public string Cognome { get; set; }
    public string CognomeNome { get; set; }
}

myVars object1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<myVars>(json);
dynamic object2 = JObject.Parse(djson); // object2 contains a field named "CognomeNome"


myVars.CognomeNome = myVars.Cognome + myVarsNome;
MapObjects(object1 , object2);
string rjson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object2); //returns {"CognomeNome":""}

public static object MapObjects(object source, object target)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo sourceProp in source.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            PropertyInfo targetProp = target.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.Name == sourceProp.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            if (targetProp != null && targetProp.GetType().Name == sourceProp.GetType().Name)
            {
                targetProp.SetValue(target, sourceProp.GetValue(source));
            }
        }
        return target;
    }
```

Comment: You'll need to add more information for your question to be answerable (example, perhaps?). Seemingly [`AutoMapper` has support](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Dynamic-and-ExpandoObject-Mapping) for `dynamic` so this presumably extends to `JObject` as well

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# - How to create a dynamic object from a static object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156815/c-sharp-how-to-create-a-dynamic-object-from-a-static-object)

Comment: You can try c# reflection to retrieve the names of the members from known object and try to check whether they exist in dynamic object. If it exists you can assign using the reflection.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to stackoverflow.  As explained in [ask], we're going to need to see some code and/or JSON to give a concrete answer; a [mcve] would be best.  But since a *dynamic object created by `JsonConvert`* is really just a [`JToken`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken.htm), you should be able to deserialize to a new concrete object using [`JToken.ToObject<T>()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_ToObject__1.htm), or populate an existing object as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30220811).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use one of the existing automappers ([Alternatives to AutoMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7052002/alternatives-to-automapper/))

For example, this:
https://github.com/agileobjects/AgileMapper/wiki/Performing-Updates sounds like it's what you are asking for.